# VirtualBox - How to solve "VT-x not available" when VT-x is turned on in BIOS?

Tags: virtualbox, bios, vt-x

I have a VirtualBox that was working before I installed Docker for windows.

Now when I try to open a VM (64bit) that was working I get the follow error:

```
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Now when I try to create a new VM I can only do it for 32bit, not 64bit any more. And if I try to create a 32bit I get a blue screen from windows.

Inside the bios I have Virtualization and VT-x enabled.

My OS is Windows 10, 64bit

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have 64bit host OS? Did you enable HyperV features in host Windows OS?

Comment: Yes I have a 64bit. I remember that during the instalation, the DockerForWindows Enebled HyperV. Is that the issue? SHould I disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a solution.
Just turn off hyper-v and virtualBox will works.

In the other hand Docker for windows displays the follow error:

[image]

Comment: It works for Windows, but probably not for Linux.